# What's the difference between "you guys" and "you folks"?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, vocabulary

*You guys* and *you folks* seem to have similar meanings. Do they have any differences? Thanks a lot

Comment: Related 1) [Is “guy” gender-neutral?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11816/is-guy-gender-neutral/106933#106933); 2) [alternatives for “guy”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6329/alternatives-for-guy/50974#50974); 3) [What is a feminine version of 'guys'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19074/what-is-a-feminine-version-of-guys/19114#19114); 4)[How to say hello to a group of people?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112941/how-to-say-hello-to-a-group-of-people/112948#112948)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me to be a difference between American, English and Australian usage preference. In Australia I hear people say 'you guys' more often than 'you folks'. Other people might be able to suggest their experience.